# Onclick Display Block to None and None to Block in jQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Simple question :

how to set other to display block only selected onlick on particular div will display block the rest will display:none.

jQUERY :

```
$('.menu_jyclass').click(function(){
            var vr=$(this).attr('vr')
            $(".table_main").hide()
            $("#main_"+vr).show();
            $('.menu_jyclass').removeClass('cur');
            $(this).addClass('cur') 
        });

      $("#hn").click(function () {
        $("#zhifubaoDiv").css("display","block")
        // $("#").show();   
    });

        $("#wx").click(function () {
        $("#wangyincunkuan2Div").css("display","block")
        // $("#").show();   
    });
```

HTML

```
  <a class="menu_jyclass" id="hn" vr="hn">微信支付</a>
  <a class="menu_jyclass cur" id="wx" vr="wx">在线支付</a>

 <div id="zhifubaoDiv" class="ListItemSub clearfix" style="display: none;">
 <div id="wangyincunkuan2Div" class="ListItemSub clearfix" style="display:none;">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Javascript:

```
$("#hn").click(function () {
        $("#wangyincunkuan2Div").css("display","none")
        $("#zhifubaoDiv").css("display","block")
        // $("#").show();   
    });

    $("#wx").click(function () {
        $("#wangyincunkuan2Div").css("display","block")
        $("#zhifubaoDiv").css("display","none")
        // $("#").show();   
    });
```

Fiddle Here: https://jsfiddle.net/c8czc69e/